# How to implement a "search within X amount of miles"

Tags: php, google-maps, search

Not a technical problem I am having but does anyone know how to implement a "search within 8 miles of City"

Im looking something like the search on the [Autotrader Site](http://www4.autotrader.co.uk/)

Are there online services (maybe a google maps api?) that do this or is it usually built by the developer.

Comment: I really doubt any developer would bother doing this themselves nowadays. Google maps is so powerful and open, their API can do what you want, I'm sure. I've never used it but their documentation seems pretty good; https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Comment: I was thinking that, but I was wondering if there would be a service that did it. I dread looking at Google APIs, just scares me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps I take to implement this:

Assuming that you are allowing user to search for cities within 8 miles, matching records from Table A, which also has a address or city field.

1. Step 1: When you are adding a new record to table A, which will be used for searching against later on, via Google Map API you can save the latitude/longitude of that address or city in each row of that table.
2. Step 2: When user types in the city keyword, again use Google Map API to fetch the latitude longitude of the search keyword city.
3. Step 3: Armed with the keyword lat/long to match against the table records lat/long, use a query with Harvensine Formula  with a "having" statement to fetch the necessary records.

The formula and the mysql query on how to do this, [is described well here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)
The google map API to use is [in this google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

One thing to note though, is that suppose you enter a city name, say "Los Angeles". It is incorrect to assume that Los Angeles is a "dot" on the map...its a city with a shape. So suppose you say all results within 5 miles of Los Angeles...the question is ambiguous because one might ask - Which end of Los Angeles? For this reason, the google api will return multiple sets of coordinates against the same city, to define the bounding poly line of the location. If your really want your results to be accurate, don't just consider 5 miles from the centre, take the other coords into consideration too, and use union of the results.

Comment: Have you worked with this sort of stuff before? Do you know if there are any video tutorials available on it

Comment: Yes I have developed 2 different sites with the exact same functionality. Don't know about video tutorials though,I thought coders like to see code more than video :)

Comment: Yeah, but I like to see how it works as its developed. That way I know exactly what goes right or wrong :) So is all the info I need in the two links?

Comment: Pretty much. Also one more thing I did is, as in my case, I was doing a parking vendor search based on "all vendors within 5 miles of where I need to park". So when the vendors registered and keyed their addresses in, I used google map api to plot on a map their location, and allowed them to move the map pointer and set it to a different location and capture those coords if they felt the geocoding was inaccurate.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add another item which had me puzzled for a while.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help. Il get looking into it during the next week. Is is hard to do?

Comment: No its not hard once you get the hang of it. Its more a matter of covering all bases rather than being an extremely clever piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for types of locations on Google Maps within X miles of a location, it can do that https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/?hl=fr&csw=1#PlaceSearches.

If you're looking for locations from a specific set of locations (like locations in a database) within X miles of a location, you'll have to do some of that yourself.  Use Google Maps to get each location's longitude and laditude, then calculate the distance away using a formula like so, http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, and then only show results that are within the distance you want.